# Deriving recursion formula for the moments about the mean of the Poisson distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I'm having trouble seeing how this recursion formula holds.

---

[image]

---

Let $a_x(\lambda) = (x - \lambda)^r \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$

Firstly, we have

$$\log a_x(\lambda) = r \log(x - \lambda) + x \log \lambda - \lambda - \log x!,$$

which we differentiate to get,

$$\frac{1}{a_x(\lambda)} \frac{da_x}{d\lambda} = \frac{r}{\lambda - x} + \frac{x}{\lambda} - 1$$

so the derivative is $$\frac{da_x}{d\lambda} = a_x(\lambda) \left( \frac{r}{\lambda - x} + \frac{x}{\lambda} - 1  \right) $$

Thus, the equality being proposed in the question, fully written out, is:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}  (x - \lambda)^{r+1} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} = \lambda \left[   
r \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (x - \lambda)^{r-1} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} + 
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (x - \lambda)^r \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \left( \frac{r}{\lambda - x} + \frac{x}{\lambda} - 1    \right) \right] 
$$

and I do not see how we can simplify the right hand side to get the left hand side. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations look correct so far.  You just have to complete it.  The RHS simplifies to

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{x+1} e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \left(r (x-\lambda)^{r-1} + (x-\lambda)^r \left( \frac{r}{\lambda - x} + \frac{x}{\lambda} - 1 \right) \right) \\
= \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{x+1} e^{-\lambda}}{x!} (x-\lambda)^r \frac{x-\lambda}{\lambda} \\
= \sum_{x=0}^\infty (x-\lambda)^{r+1} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}.$$

In the first line, we factored out the terms $\lambda^{x+1}$, $e^{-\lambda}$, and $x!$.  In the second step, we observe that the first term in parentheses cancels with the product $(x-\lambda)^r \cdot r/(\lambda - x)$.  In the last step, we note the product $(x-\lambda)^r (x/\lambda - 1) = (x-\lambda)^{r+1}/\lambda$.